# What is the scientific calculation method of 0xf.ap+11 hexadecimal to decimal?

Tags: hex, hexdump

Your similar hex ox2ab, aef97, etc, I understand its scientific notation, but
0xf.ap+11 makes me wonder.Can anyone help me, thanks!

Comment: _"I understand its scientific notation..."_ Where do you get this understanding from? Your numbers are not hex, did you mean **0x2AB** when you say **ox2ab**? What notation does that make?

Comment: I have solved it thanks！

Answer (score 0):

It is the *hexadecimal floating-point representation* available with C99.

The significant portion `0xf.a` is expressed in the way each digit has
the power of 16 according to the position:

```
0xf.a = 0xf (= 15 * 16^0) + 0x.a (= 10 * 16^-1)
      = 15 + 10 / 15
```

while the exponent portion indicates the power of two:

```
p+11 = 2^11
```

then

```
0xf.ap+11 = (15 + 10 / 16) * 2048
          = 30720 + 1280
          = 32000
```

In actual C code you can say something like:

```
int main()
{
    double x = 0xf.ap+11;
    printf("%f\n", x);          // it will print 32000.000000

    double y = 32000.0;
    printf("%a\n", y);          // it will print 0x1.f4p+14

    return 0;
}
```

You'll find the both `0xf.ap+11` and `0x1.f4p+14` are equal to `32000.0`. It looks surprising two different expression have the identical numbers.